# gcloud is crashing while authenticating service account key with error: gcloud crashed (OperationalError): disk I/O error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I am trying to run the following command: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service_account_key.json`

Post which I get an error output as below:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OperationalError): disk I/O error

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Running gcloud diagnostics comes clean with below output:

```
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).
```

Earlier the diagnostics used to give error that google services are not reachable which was fixed by setting up the proxy and then authentication started to work. but now it is failing with proxy settings as is(proxy works fine).

Neither diagnostics is giving enough info about the crash nor the error message itself.

below are the gcloud version info:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 254.0.0
bq 2.0.45
core 2019.07.15
gsutil 4.40
Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

I have also tried --verbose that too was not of much help.

Comment: Are you able to try this command from another host? That would help eliminate your local `gcloud` installation as the issue. You may wish to try the command using Cloud Shell. You can `gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp ...` (the key file) and then `gcloud alpha-cloud-shell ssh` into Cloud Shell to retry the command.

Comment: I tried running the command from my local as well as from cloud shell both ran successfully. Even if something is wrong with the installation considering someone on shared host messed it up. As it was working earlier, I'm unable to drill down the issue because of error msg.

Comment: The only occurrences of the `OperationalError` appear to be with sqlite (https://www.google.com/search?q=OperationalError+disk+I%2FO+error). I assume (!?) `gcloud` uses it to store config (`~/.config/gcloud`). If true, it's possible that there's some corruption in one of these files and that's causing the issue. If you have Google Support, that may be a good next step.

Comment: Think to update your GCLOUD SDK first. you are 50 versions behind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @guillaume I updated the gcloud SDK to the latest version and got more verbose error message post which I was able to fix the issue.

```
WARNING: Could not store access token in cache: disk I/O error
[Step 1/1] ERROR: gcloud crashed (OperationalError): disk I/O error
```

The default location where the gcloud was writing configs(/.config/gcloud) needed a clean-up. We updated the config directory itself to a new dir as we had limited access to earlier pointed directory otherwise a clean-up would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to gcloud config folder

```
cd ~/.config/gcloud
```

2. Make empty `access_token.db` file from the gcloud config folder

```
> access_tokens.db
```

3. Now activate the service account

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service_account_key.json
```